# how come gcc doesnt complain about assigning a 64 bit value to a 32 bit

Tags: gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
        int x;
        size_t xx = 12345678901234;
        x = xx;
        printf("%d %zi %zi\n", x, sizeof(x), sizeof(xx));
}
```

compiled with -Wall -pedantic gcc doesnt say anything. When run it produces

```
1942892530 4 8
```

Comment: Try adding `-Wconversion`, see https://godbolt.org/z/Me96o58WT.

Comment: @ssbssa - yup found that. Was stunned by the fact that it required such aggressive flags to enable such a basic error.